# Javascript fillRect does not draw from variable

Tags: javascript, canvas, jsfiddle

How come context.fillRect(10, 10, 20, 20) fills a rectangle, but when using variables like player.x or player.y, it won't work?

If I ask the value of player.x in the JavaScript console, it returns 300. But when using player.x in fillRect, JavaScript draws a blank.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")
var player = {}
player.x = 300
player.y = 80

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    context.fillRect(10, 10, 20, 20) //works as intended
    context.fillRect(player.x, player.y, 20, 20) //does not work
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xy4h4obw/1/

Comment: It's not that you are using a variable. The problem is that the x, y coordinates are out of the canvas. If you set player.x = 10 and player.y = 10, it works. If you use context.fillRect(300, 80, 20, 20) you get a white canvas.

Comment: How could I have overlooked this?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine if you make the canvas wide enough:

http://jsfiddle.net/stmdet8c/

Or set `player.x` to a smaller value